# How to check equality for a custom class array in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, equality

I have a custom class named as `City` and this class has an `Equals` method. The `SequenceEqual` method works good when comparing arrays with assigned variables. The problem occurs when comparing two arrays that contains the elements formatted `new  City()`. It results as false.

**City class:**

```
interface IGene : IEquatable<IGene>
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    int Index { get; set; }
}
class City : IGene
{
    string name;
    int index;
    public City(string name, int index)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.index = index;
    }
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return name;
        }
        set
        {
            name = value;
        }
    }

    public int Index
    {
        get
        {
            return index;
        }
        set
        {
            index = value;
        }
    }

    public bool Equals(IGene other)
    {
        if (other == null && this == null)
            return true;
        if((other is City))
        {
            City c = other as City;
            return c.Name == this.Name && c.Index == this.Index;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

In the `Test` method below, the first comparing result `arrayCompare1` is `true` and the second result `arrayCompare2` is `false`. Both compare result must be true but there is an anormal stuation. How can I fix this problem?

**Test code:**

```
public void Test()
{
    City c1 = new City("A", 1);
    City c2 = new City("B", 2);

    City[] arr1 = new City[] { c1, c2 };
    City[] arr2 = new City[] { c1, c2 };

    City[] arr3 = new City[] { new City("A", 1), new City("B", 2) };
    City[] arr4 = new City[] { new City("A", 1), new City("B", 2) };

    bool arrayCompare1 = arr1.SequenceEqual(arr2);
    bool arrayCompare2 = arr3.SequenceEqual(arr4);

    MessageBox.Show(arrayCompare1 + " " + arrayCompare2);
}
```

Comment: this condition is useless `this == null`

Comment: Thanks for the response @CodeNotFound. You're right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to override the Object.Equals somehow like this:

```
public override bool Equals(object other)
{
    if (other is IGene)
        return Equals((IGene)other);
    return base.Equals(other);
}
```

Comment: Ok, It worked. But the overridden `Equals` method is not implemented by the `IEquatable` interface and it seems the `Equals` method that comes from the `IEquatable` interface doesn't be used in array comparisons. I need to be sure the class inherited from the `IGene` interface contains overridden `Equals` method. How can I do that?

Comment: In that case don't have the class implement IEquateable instead create a separate class that implements IEqualityComparer <IGene> then pass that comparer to SequenceEqual

Answer (score 2):

You need to override bool Equals(**object** obj). Simplest addition to your code:

```
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return Equals(obj as IGene);
    }
```